# How to export SSRS Report to Excel with fit columns

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a simple Reporting Services report with a simple table. When I export to Excel, a column in the report does not match the column in Excel. That causes a lot of difficulties when working with Excel
How can I fix this?  I have tried many ways but it does not work
Thanks a lot
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EuuE.jpg)

Comment: have you fixed the column format?
Can you provide some othe details and show an example?

Comment: I just added an illustration. please see it

Comment: I think I know the reason. Because I added the textbox above the table, the column in Excel will follow that textbox.

And the question now is How do I add a text box in ssrs report so that the table column in ssrs still matches the column in Excel

Answer (score 0):

SSRS is pixel-perfect. It means that what is represented with the pixels will be **precisely** represented in the report. The consequence of this is that the objects you add in the design area must be perfectly aligned if you don't want to create extra columns in the Excel rendering.

Sometimes this is tricky, and the more objects you have, the more complicated it is to obtain an Excel file without extra columns.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Use the property table and don't move objects in the design area with your mouse pointer.
2. Always start with the first object from the location (left/top location=0, 0).
3. Left-align all the objects at the design area border (left location=0).
4. Use fixed numbers for the width and height of the columns and their multiples if they need to be larger.

In short, this is your best ally:
[image]

With bigger report use pages! This can be accomplished using the "PageBreak" and "PageName" properties.

Regarding your question the width of the text box must match the witdh of the columns under it.
Like in this example:

[image]

Position of the textbox:

[image]

Position of the table:

[image]

As you can see the two object are left and right perfectly aligned and this is the result. No extra columns and no extra rows.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestions help me a lot. I fixed the width of the cells, set the location of tables at (0in, 0in), and used the "Page Break". My problem was solved.